# Angular2 Http post request not binding to ASP.NET 5 controller's action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, angular

I am initiating a post request from Angular2 to a ASP.NET 5 controller action. Angular is posting the data correctly and hitting the controller action but it is not being mapped to the parameters defined in controller action, the parameters are `null`. Meanwhile by inspecting through `Request` object `Request.Form` has the correct textual data but not binding to the model.

Angular

```
let body = JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'Ali' });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

this.http.post(this.url, body, { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log('Response received');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (err) => { console.log('Error'); },
                () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
            );
```

ASP.NET

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DemoAction(string firstName)
{
      var req = Request;

      return null;
}
```

Request.Form has data in the form like `{\"firstName\":\"Ali\"}` but the parameter `firstName` is `null`

Comment: Why are you "stringifying" the json? Just post the json object.

Comment: The body param of http.post needs to be a string

Comment: Have you tried directly posting the data?

Comment: Yes, its the same. firstName param is null and Request.Form has a value like [object Object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to send a JSON content (created using the JSON.stringify method) with a content type url encoded form.

You should try to use the application/json one:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'Ali' });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

this.http.post(this.url, body, { headers: headers })
```

**Edit**

If you want to provide a form content, you could leverage the `URLSearchParams` class:

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('firstName', 'Ali');
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });

this.http.post(this.url, params.toString(), { headers: headers })
```

Comment: The same with content-type application/json firstName is null and even the  Form.Request is also null

Comment: I have a complete model with many properties, how can I set them to URLSearchParams ?

Comment: single parameter is receiving correctly using URLSearchParams, but how can I post an object (model)

Comment: I understand. What do you exactly mean by "parameter"? Is it a query parameter or a property of the request payload?

Comment: Property of request payload that you are sending as a parameter as params.set('firstName', 'Ali'); now I want to send a complete object/model with set of properties. Should I manually set each property in params.set ?

Comment: In fact parameters are a set of key / value. So you can convert it by hand for the first level using this class and a for / in loop...

Comment: For complete object you should consider to use the request payload itself with the JSON format...

Comment: With JSON I am getting null in controller's action parameter

Comment: I have loop through each property of object and set them to params object. Now its working and I am getting the data. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 3):

In this case you don't require to pass the header. look at here. you may try this.

```
this.http.post('/api/ControllerName/DemoAction?firstName=Ali')
.subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log('Response received');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (err) => { console.log('Error'); },
                () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
            );
```

This will surely work.

---

***Edited:***

**Figured out** your problem.

**First: When you are receiving paramter(s) at API end , you must use above portion.**

**second: When you are receiving `object` at API end, you must use below code.**

I'm showing you with my setup as I don't know your object at server side.

```
let um=JSON.stringify({ Username: "Hello1",Password:"Hello2"});

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

this.http.post(this.url+'/Authentication',um,{ headers: headers })
                        .subscribe(...);
```

At server side I have following setup.

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Authentication(UserModel um)  // I m getting value here.
{
    if (um.Username == "a" && um.Password == "a")
    {
        um.Username = um.Username;
        um.Password = um.Password;
        return Ok(um);
    }
    return NotFound();
}
```

Simple solution !! isn't it?

Comment: I have a complete model with many properties, firstName is just for demonstration. I don't want to create a querystring manually

Comment: I find it more simple but unfortunately I am getting null with this solution

Comment: Which content-type you used ?

Comment: Oh sorry ! forgot to tell you. Updating  answer.

Comment: Still not getting the values

Comment: In my case its working fine. Why don't you make my shown model and implement the same?

Comment: if you are facing any problem you can raise a new question with relevant data of yours and I or somebody else will try to solve it.

Comment: I have copy/paste your example but still not getting the values. For now, I have used the above method by Thierry Templier using URLSearchParams(). Thanks a lot for your time and help :-)

Comment: Have you implented this in ASP.NET 5 ?

Comment: Nope as I don't have ASP.NET5. I implemented it with MVC4 template and installed following packages through NuGet. Web-Api, CORS, HelpPage,MVC.  all latest packages.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'Ali' }), { headers: headers })
```