# Typescript/Angular2 http.post doesn't set headers

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to post json from Angular2 beta 8 but the headers aren't being transmitted:

```typescript
import { RequestOptions, RequestMethod, RequestHeaders, RequestOptionsArgs, Http } from 'angular2/http';

// ...
let headers = new Headers(),
    body = JSON.stringify({ identifier, password });

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
let opts:RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers };

this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'auth/login', body, opts)
    .subscribe(
         data => console.log(data),
         err => console.log(err.json().message),
         () => console.log('Authentication Complete')
    );
```

But the XHR call in Chrome doesn't have either of these headers.  Chrome debug shows that the `Content-Type` header is flagged `Provisional Headers are Shown` and shows `Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8`.  The header values seem to be correct though:

```javascript
console.log(headers.get('Content-Type')) // => 'application/json'
console.log(headers.get('Accept'))       // => 'application/json'
```

---

The problem is that I'm pulling in `RequestHeaders`, but it should just be `Headers`.  Why it didn't give me an error, I don't know.

Comment: Can you check this post ? probably it can solve your problem. [Angular2 How to get token by sending credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442569/angular2-how-to-get-token-by-sending-credentials)

Comment: read this asnwer for use of  `Header` http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to import the `Headers` class like this (you forgot it in your import from `angular2/http`):

```
import {
  RequestOptions,
  RequestMethod,
  RequestHeaders,
  RequestOptionsArgs,
  Http,
  Headers // <------
} from 'angular2/http';

// ...
let headers = new Headers(),
body = JSON.stringify({ identifier, password });
```

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2/Http (POST) headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35032465/angular2-http-post-headers/35032846#35032846)