# Angular2 http post not passing the json object to MVC 6 controller action

Tags: http-post, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an angular 2 application using asp.net MVC6. Angular2 Http post method calls the controller action and works properly when there is no parameter/properties, but when i add a parameter to the controller action, The expected JSON mapping is not happening while trying to call action with the parameter values. Debugging the action shows  null value to the parameter.
I tested with all the solutions provided in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432527/angular2-http-post-request-not-binding-to-asp-net-5-controllers-action#comment58564010_35432972) , but still i am getting the null value for the parameter.

[debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq6HB.png)

**Here is my code**

> 1.Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addNewUser(string name) //tested with [FromBody]
{
     return Json(name);
}
```

> 2.angular2 http post

```
--UserComponent.ts
this.userService.AddUser(name).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.toggle('list');
            }
        );

--UserService.ts        
AddUser(name: string) {
        return this.ExecutePost('addNewUser', name).map((newUser: string) => { return newUser });
    }

--BaseService.ts
protected ExecutePost(action: string, name: string) {
        let body = JSON.stringify({ name: name });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });

        return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + action, body, { headers: headers })
            .map(res => { return res.json(); }).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I am able to access the same action with Jquery ajax and it is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/addNewUser",
            data: { 'name': 'cebeDev' }
        })

    });
```

Or, Is there anything am missing on the startup.cs file?

> Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

[Please find the request details from dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl9V0.png)

Comment: Could you provide the content of the HTTP request that is sent from the Network tab of dev tools in your browser? Your Angular2 seems fine. The only thing could be that you forgot to import the `Headers` class...

Comment: hi @ThierryTemplier, I have updated the post with the request details, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671333/6063346) and now I am able to post the Json data using angular2 Http request method instead of post.The controller action shows the object values while debugging. I have tested with the different types of objects and list of objects and everything is working fine.

Thanks @Pardeep Jain for your sample code.

**BaseService.ts**

```
protected ExecutePost(action: string, data: any) {
        let _body = JSON.stringify(data);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });

        let requestoptions: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this._baseUrl + action,
            headers: headers,
            body: _body
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => { return res.json(); });
    }
```