# Angular 2 post data is null in asp.net MVC 6

Tags: c#, typescript, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

At the moment I'm using **Angular 2 Beta-9** together with **Asp.Net MVC 6**.
I'm trying to create a simple contact form as test. The problem is that my form data does not seem to get passed to the server, while everything seems to be going ok on the Angular side.

**contact.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts" />

import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'contact',
    bindings: [ContactComponent],
    viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
    templateUrl: '/angular/contact'
})

export class ContactComponent {
    http = undefined;
    contact = {};

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.http.post('/contact/send', JSON.stringify(this.contact), new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })).subscribe();
    }
}

bootstrap(ContactComponent);
```

**Contact.cshtml**

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contact)">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.Name" class="form-control text-input" id="name" placeholder="Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <input type="email" [(ngModel)]="contact.Email" class="form-control text-input" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.Subject" class="form-control text-input" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Bericht</label>
                <textarea type="text" [(ngModel)]="contact.Message" class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**ContactController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendContact([FromBody]ContactVm contact)
{
    //do something
}
```

**ContactVm.cs**

```
public class ContactVm
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't see or find anything I'm doing wrong. Untill the *http.post*, *this.contact* is filled in like it should, but once it reaches the server it's *null*.

**UPDATE**

Found that the *Request.Form* is throwing the following error:

```
Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: could you add `/angular/contact` template, contact variable binded correctly or not..

Comment: Added the template and contact model I'm using the controller.
Although I think the view is ok, since I noticed during debugging that everything is passed correctly to the Post function.

Comment: did you tried the below answer, with what I've suggested?

Comment: @JeffreyRosselle did  you look at the request being sent were the properties there and it just didn't model bind? Did you try explicitly binding the name instead of [(ngModel)]="contact.Name" name="contact.Name"

Comment: Could you try `this.http.post('/contact/send', JSON.stringify({ contact: this.contact}), new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }))`

Comment: @johnny5 unfortunately that didn't change anything either. I did just noticed that in the header, received at the server, the ContentType is 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' while I clearly pass 'application/json'

Comment: @PankajParkar no luck either on the last comment.

Comment: @JeffreyRosselle did you see the parameters you passed atleast, if the content type is text im not sure if the model binder will work with that

Comment: it looks like my Request.Form us throwing an error: "'HttpContext.Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'" => "Incorrect Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: @JeffreyRosselle see below, i have used this for my endpoint calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

this.http.post('/contact/send',JSON.stringify(this.contact),{ headers: headers })
         .subscribe(...);
```

**server side**.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SendContact(ContactVm contact)
{
    //do something
}
```

If it doesn't work also see below selected answer.

- [Angular2 Http post request not binding to ASP.NET 5 controller's action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432527/angular2-http-post-request-not-binding-to-asp-net-5-controllers-action/35432972#35432972)\

Comment: I check the link and it finally worked when I used the "URLSearchParams()" object.
Although it is fixed for me, I'd like to find a solution where I don't have to map my object to URLSearchParams.

Comment: You should accept it as an answer so when other users come to this post may get the right direction...Btw glad it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have found, MVC will "fail silently" if it cannot force your posted value into the parameter.

So, while I am developing I used "object" - which ensures I get ALL posts. And then I fine tune it back to refer to the correct object.

Also, I found that (in Angular 6 which I am using) you definitely don't need to JSON.stringify the object... Look at the Chome Inspect tab, at the POST, an then Preview, and it will give you some detail of the failing...

Comment: Correct about the JSON.stringify, I think I made this post when it was still in beta, and for some reason I needed to stringfy it. It has been updated since then, and I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
getJsonHeader(): Headers {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        return headers;
    }

   onSubmit() {
        this.http.post('/contact/send', JSON.stringify(this.contact), { headers: this.getJsonHeader() }).subscribe();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need JSON.stringify:

this.http.post('/contact/send', this.contact, new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })).subscribe();

This corrected my issue HTH